# How can I get live bitmap image with Camera2 extension API

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-camera, android-camera2

I am using [Camera2 Extension](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Extensions) example for real time image processing. Before that I was using [Camera2 Basic](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Basic). In Basic sample I was getting real-time image as from below code snippet.

```
val captureRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(
    CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW
).apply {
    addTarget(getViewDataBinding()?.viewFinder!!.holder.surface)
    addTarget(imageReader.surface)
}

// This will keep sending the capture request as frequently as possible until the
// session is torn down or session.stopRepeating() is called
captureRequest.set(
    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,
    CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
)
captureRequest.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest.build(), null, cameraHandler)
```

You can see that, I added target **imageReader** in above code. I am using almost similar way with extension API. But in **ExtensionSessionConfiguration** configured method.

```
cameraExtensionSession = session
try {
    val captureRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(
        CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW
    ).apply {
        addTarget(previewSurface)
        addTarget(imageReader.surface)
    }
    captureRequest.set(
        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,
        CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
    )
    cameraExtensionSession.setRepeatingRequest(
        captureRequest.build(),
        Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor(), captureCallbacks
    )
} catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
    Toast.makeText(
        this@LiveCameraActivity, "Failed to preview capture request.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()
    finish()
}
```

Above code giving me error like below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid repeating request output target!
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraExtensionSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraExtensionSessionImpl.java:442)
    at com.cherish.smartcam.ui.liveCamera.LiveCameraActivity$startPreview$extensionConfiguration$1.onConfigured(CameraActivity.kt:399)
```

I have configured image as JPEG. My problem here,

- How can I get live bitmap image with Camera2 extension API?
- Is there anything wrong in above code?

Comment: few people in `image-processing` know much about android APIs. you should have tagged `android` and `java` because the other two tags are monitored by almost nobody.

Comment: Well, how do you initialize the `previewSurface` in the second code snippet? I think we need a bit more context here.

Comment: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Extensions Checkout this repository

Comment: @KrunalKapadiya See [this example file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/camera2/impl/CameraExtensionSessionImpl.java), does line **470** help you to understand your error? It's telling you that your `captureRequest.getTargets().size()` is not **1**. Maybe check with: `var tempNum = myRequest.getTargets().size()` then `print("captureRequest Target SIZE : $tempNum")` ... If it is not **1** then your target is **not ready/available**. Try putting first the `.build` result into a variable before later using `session.setRepeatingRequest`

Comment: I can see, but I added target after initialisation of stillImagereader and there is no method to check getTarget().size(). @VC.One